# Toggle color of cells on click (Tkinter-Python)

Tags: python, image, dataframe, tkinter

I am a PhD student in biochemistry analyzing image intensity from microscope pictures. My analysis software Metamorph acquires all the information from 384-well plates and quantifies it into an excel workbook. By trying to create a 16x24 grid on Tkinter, I want to map the analysis values of each well in excel to its particular position on the 16x24 grid. I want the user to be able to click on a cell in the 16x24 tkinter grid and have it appear to be a color. But everytime I click the button again, it changes colors. Whatever color the cells determine which group they belong to. For example, if I click through a row of cells that all recieved 5uM drug, originally they would all appear blank but then they would all appear "blue" for instance, and then all blue cells would be averaged. If I click on the cell twice, it goes first from white to blue, then blue to green, and then all the green cells would become averaged.

I have gotten up to the part where I begin coding some sort of "toggle-switch", that I'd like to go between colors but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to implement it. I found this code from some stackoverflow post before that shapes into almost what I want. I realize that the first class, Cell, has the _switch function that goes between the *is self.fill* and *NOT self.fill*, but I'm wondering if there would be any changes needed to be **draw function** or **mousehandling** that would be needed.

Sorry for the naiveness, I'm self-taught and don't really have a strong background in python, trying to learn :)

the following is the code: 
i've tried to implement a dictionary where each entry in it was a color, but that didn't work.

```
class Cell():
    FILLED_COLOR_BG = "blue"
    EMPTY_COLOR_BG = "white"
    FILLED_COLOR_BORDER = "black"
    EMPTY_COLOR_BORDER = "black"


def __init__(self, master, x, y, size):
    """ Constructor of the object called by Cell(...) """
    self.master = master
    self.abs = x
    self.ord = y
    self.size = size 
    self.fill = False

def _switch(self):
    """ Switch if the cell is filled or not. """
    self.fill = not self.fill 

def draw(self):
    """ order to the cell to draw its representation on the canvas """
    if self.master != None:  
        fill = Cell.FILLED_COLOR_BG[self.fancy()]
        outline = Cell.FILLED_COLOR_BORDER
        if not self.fill:
            fill = Cell.EMPTY_COLOR_BG
            outline = Cell.EMPTY_COLOR_BORDER

        xmin = self.abs * self.size
        xmax = xmin + self.size
        ymin = self.ord * self.size
        ymax = ymin + self.size
        self.master.create_rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, fill=fill, outline=outline)
class CellGrid(Canvas):
def __init__(self, master, rowNumber, columnNumber, cellSize, *args, **kwargs):
    Canvas.__init__(self, master, width=cellSize * columnNumber, height=cellSize * rowNumber, *args, **kwargs)

    self.cellSize = cellSize

    self.grid = []
    for row in range(rowNumber):

        line = []
        for column in range(columnNumber):
            line.append(Cell(self, column, row, cellSize))

        self.grid.append(line)

    # memorize the cells that have been modified to avoid many switching of state during mouse motion.
    self.switched = []

    # bind click action
    self.bind("<Button-1>", self.handleMouseClick)
    # bind moving while clicking
    self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.handleMouseMotion)
    # bind release button action - clear the memory of midified cells.
    self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: self.switched.clear())

    self.draw()


def title(self):
    for row in self.grid:
        for cell in row:
            cell.append(row)

def draw(self):
    for row in self.grid:
        for cell in row:
            cell.draw()

def _eventCoords(self, event):
    row = int(event.y / self.cellSize)
    column = int(event.x / self.cellSize)
    return row, column

def handleMouseClick(self, event):
    row, column = self._eventCoords(event)
    cell = self.grid[row][column]
    cell._switch()
    cell.draw()
    # add the cell to the list of cell switched during the click
    self.switched.append(cell)

def handleMouseMotion(self, event):
    row, column = self._eventCoords(event)
    cell = self.grid[row][column]

    if cell not in self.switched:
        cell._switch()
        cell.draw()
        self.switched.append(cell)

def showCallback(self, record):
    """ returns a callback for self.show """

    def callback():  # make a new function
        return self.show(record)  # that shows the given record

    return callback  # return this function



if __name__ == "__main__":
app = Tk()

grid = CellGrid(app, 16, 24, 30)
grid.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Removing Excel tag, since the question is not about Excel.

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem you are facing. The color changes just fine when I remove `[self.fancy()]` in `fill = Cell.FILLED_COLOR_BG[self.fancy()]`. Or do you mean you want to toggle between a bunch of colors instead of just two?